# React: update URL with id from Select

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have the following component (it is just some wrapper on Select and inside this Component most of properties are assigned to `<Select>` component):

```
        <FormSelectNative
            options={games}
            valueKey="id"
            labelKey="name"
            onChange={handleGameSelect}
            defaultValue={games[0].id}
          />
```

And here is handleGameSelect method that is run onChange Select event. It loads data new data.

```
 const handleGameSelect = event => {
    axios.get(`/games/${event.target.value}`).then(function (response) {
      const { game, backgrounds, categories } = response.data;
      setData({ game, backgrounds, categories });
    });
  };
```

There is no page reload here.
I need to update `Url` with {event.target.value} value. So that when user will press Refresh or Copy link, he will be able to navigate to the same data.

But not sure how to do this?